# How to replace empty string with zero in comma-separated string?

Tags: python, string

"8,5,,1,4,7,,,,7,,1,9,3,6,,,8,6,3,9,,2,5,4,,,,,3,2,,,7,4,1,1,,4,,6,9,,5,,,,5,,,1,,6,3,,,6,5,,,,7,4,,1,7,6,,,,8,,5,,,7,1,,3,9,"

I'm doing a programming challenge where i need to parse this sequence into my sudoku script.
Need to get the above sequence into 8,5,0,1,4,7,0,0,0,7,0,1,9,3,6,0,0,8.........
I tried re but without success, help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Fun question and great opportunity to write really idiomatic Python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use

```
[(int(x) if x else 0) for x in data.split(',')]
```

`data.split(',')` splits the string into a list. It splits on the comma character:

```
['8', '5', '', '1', '4', '7', '', '', '', ...]
```

The expression

```
(int(x) if x else 0)
```

returns `int(x)` if `x` is True, 0 if `x` is False. Note that the empty string is False.

Comment: Thanks for the help, its really clear the way you and Dietrich Epp explained it.

Answer (score 5):

Regular expressions are often unnecessary in Python.  Given string `s`, try:

```
','.join(x or '0' for x in s.split(','))
```

I am assuming you want to fill the blanks with 0.  If you want a list of integers instead of a string, try this:

```
[(x and int(x)) or 0 for x in s.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
s = "8,5,,1,4,7,,,,7,,1,9,3,6,,,8,6,3,9,,2,5,4,,,,,3,2,,,7,4,1,1,,4,,6,9,,5,,,,5,,,1,,6,3,,,6,5,,,,7,4,,1,7,6,,,,8,,5,,,7,1,,3,9,"
s = re.sub('((?<=,)|^)(?=,|$)', '0', s)
print s
```

Prints:

`8,5,0,1,4,7,0,0,0,7,0,1,9,3,6,0,0,8,6,3,9,0,2,5,4,0,0,0,0,3,2,0,0,7,4,1,1,0,4,0,6,9,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,1,0,6,3,0,0,6,5,0,0,0,7,4,0,1,7,6,0,0,0,8,0,5,0,0,7,1,0,3,9,0`

Comment: Wow thats insane, your a genius dude.

Comment: I agree with the "insane" part: I like to try writing those reges in order to test my skills, but for real programs, I'd rather use one of the other solutions posted here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s="8,5,,1,4,7,,,,7,,1,9,3,6,,,8,6,3,9,,2,5,4,,,,,3,2,,,7,4,1,1,,4,,6,9,,5,,,,5,,,1,,6,3,,,6,5,,,,7,4,,1,7,6,,,,8,,5,,,7,1,,3,9,"
>>> s=s.split(",")
>>> for n,i in enumerate(s):
...     if i=="" : s[n]=0
...
>>> s
['8', '5', 0, '1', '4', '7', 0, 0, 0, '7', 0, '1', '9', '3', '6', 0, 0, '8', '6', '3', '9', 0, '2', '5', '4', 0, 0, 0, 0, '3', '2', 0, 0, '7', '4', '1', '1', 0, '4', 0, '6', '9', 0, '5', 0, 0, 0, '5', 0, 0, '1', 0, '6', '3', 0, 0, '6', '5', 0, 0, 0, '7', '4', 0, '1', '7', '6', 0, 0, 0, '8', 0, '5', 0, 0, '7', '1', 0, '3', '9', 0]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest I can think of is

```
[int(x or 0) for x in s.split(',')]
```

or

```
[int('0'+x) for x in s.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses `map`,`lambda`, and `split`. The final code looks like this:

```
sudoku_string = "1,2,3,,4,5,,6"
output_string = map(lambda x: '0' if x=='' else x, sudoku_string.split(","))
```

If you want the output as a list (i.e. `[1,2,3,0,4,5,0,6]`), then use

```
output_list = map(lambda x: 0 if x=='' else int(x), sudoku_string.split(",")
```

The commands `map` and `lambda` are very useful. `map` takes in a function and a list (really an iterable, but that's another story), and applies the function to every element of this list. So

```
def plus_one(x):
    return x+1
map(plus_one, [1,2,3,4])
```

returns `[2,3,4,5]`. `lambda` is a way to quickly define functions, so we can write `plus_one` as

```
lambda x: x+1
```

Lastly, `split` takes a string and creates a list  by 'splitting' the string by the argument you pass. So `"1 2 3 4".split(" ")` yields `[1,2,3,4]`.